# How do I align a <div> to the center of a <div>?

Tags: css, html

I'm using HTML/CSS to make a website and on my home page I have some `<div>` tags that are inside `<div>` tags. I can't seem to get the inner `<div>` tags to align to the center of the outer `<div>` tags. Here is the HTML code i am using (the one with the stars next to it is the one that I want to align);

```
    <div id="container">
<div align="center" id="box" style="background-color:black;width:375px;height:400px;border:0px solid #003300;">
<h1 id="heading"></h1>
<h2 id="otherheading"></h2>
**<div align="center" id="box" style="background-color:white;width:275px;height:225px;border:0px solid #003300;">**
<ul class="list-tick">
    <li></li>
    <hr>
    <li></li>
    <hr>
    <li></li>
    <hr>
    <li></li>
    <hr>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1125px;
}

#container div {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 375px;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you have further questions about the problem, I will try and explain in more detail.

Comment: You cannot align it because it's floated left. Why is it floated?

Comment: They were set to float left to allow the outer <div> elements to align next to each other, without float left they align under each other

Comment: Your code is a real mess. You are mixing inline styles, style sheet, and obsolete attributes. You have different elements with the same id,  closing tags for several elements missing, and almost no intendation in the markup. Do you really want to throw all this to the community?

Comment: Sorry i'm only an Apprentice at the moment and i'm still learning. This is something I really want to do so anything that i'm doing wrong, if you could let me know and let me know what I should do to fix the problem that would be fantastic!

Comment: @GregoryLittle What have you tried to solve your problem and what have you googled?

Comment: Just how to align <div>s inside <div>s. I basically want 3 boxes next to each other with 3 boxes centered inside those boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the floats, and add these

```
#container div {
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center Horizontally */
  height: 400px;
  width: 375px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
#box
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to center align content in css.
However you can use a little trick to solve this problem.

You can see my solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/kh7UT/

Ofc, you should not have the borders, they are simple there to demonstrate the trick.
It's not the most beutiful markup, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div#box
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:275px;
}
```

Setting margin-left, margin-right to 'auto' will automatically adjust left and right for the container, i.e making it center.